# .NET Core 2.1 Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL Code-First

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I create a project in which I would like to connect to an SQLite provider for testing purposes, and use PostgreSQL on production.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt)
{
 #if DEBUG
  opt.UseSqlite("Data Source=blogging.db");
 #endif
 #if !DEBUG     
  opt.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=xxxx;Username=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx");
 #endif
}
```

I would like to use the code-first strategy. For SQLite - no problem:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

In conclusion, is there a similar solution for PostgeSQL (OpenSource)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with postgreSQL just like you are saying.

I use this 2 nugget packages:

- Npgsql;
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

And I just add this to your Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices:

```
options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And this to appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {

       "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=postgresTest;User Id=postgres;Password=xyz;"
 }
```

And then I just add a Migration and Update the DB:

1. dotnet ef migrations add MigrationTest
2. dotnet ef database update

Then everything work fine. I hope that this can help you :)